# A simple 3x3 Dice Game in Java

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a dice game where 2 players have their own dice, each has his own turn to throw his dice , players can either lose the score entirely or gain score depending on where they stand on the window , and the game ends when any player stands on the finish lane first , the winner is the player with the highest score, I've worked on the design of the game so far but haven't worked on the logic yet.

This link is a picture of how the game should look like :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej3RO.png]

I would like to know how can I add the player 1 and player 2 as in the photo above on each tile , so basically every time time a player plays his turn ,I want his name to start moving depending on the number he gets when he throws the dice.

**Code :**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class diceGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {
new RollDicePanel();
}
 }
class RollDicePanel extends JFrame {
private Dice myLeftDie;
private Dice myRightDie;
JPanel mainPanel;
JPanel topLeft,topCenter,topRight;
JPanel centerLeft,centerCenter,centerRight;
JPanel bottomLeft,bottomCenter,bottomRight;
JLabel tLeft,tRight,tCenter,cLeft,cCenter1,cCenter2,cRight,bLeft,bCenter,bRight;
RollDicePanel() {

myLeftDie  = new Dice();
myRightDie = new Dice();

JButton rollButton1 = new JButton("Player 1");
rollButton1.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 5));
rollButton1.addActionListener(new RollListener1());

JButton rollButton2 = new JButton("Player 2");
rollButton2.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 5));
rollButton2.addActionListener(new RollListener2());

topLeft = new JPanel();
tLeft = new JLabel("+20");
tLeft.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
tLeft.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
topLeft.add(tLeft,BorderLayout.WEST);
topLeft.setBackground(Color.RED);

topRight = new JPanel();
tRight = new JLabel("-50");
tRight.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
topRight.add(tRight,BorderLayout.EAST);
topRight.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

topCenter = new JPanel();
tCenter = new JLabel("Try Again");
tCenter.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
topCenter.add(tCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);
topCenter.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

centerCenter = new JPanel();
cCenter1 = new JLabel("Player 1");
cCenter2 = new JLabel("Player 2");
centerCenter.add(rollButton1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
centerCenter.add(myLeftDie,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
centerCenter.add(rollButton2,BorderLayout.NORTH);
centerCenter.add(myRightDie,BorderLayout.EAST);

centerLeft = new JPanel();
cLeft = new JLabel("Finish");
cLeft.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
centerLeft.add(cLeft,BorderLayout.WEST);
centerLeft.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

centerRight = new JPanel();
cRight = new JLabel("Lost All");
cRight.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
centerRight.add(cRight,BorderLayout.EAST);
centerRight.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

bottomRight = new JPanel();
bRight = new JLabel("+30");
bRight.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
bottomRight.add(bRight,BorderLayout.EAST);
bottomRight.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

bottomCenter = new JPanel();
bCenter = new JLabel("+10");
bCenter.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
bottomCenter.add(bCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);
bottomCenter.setBackground(Color.magenta);

bottomLeft = new JPanel();
bLeft = new JLabel("-10");
bLeft.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
bLeft.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
bottomLeft.add(bLeft,BorderLayout.WEST);
bottomLeft.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
mainPanel.add(topLeft,BorderLayout.NORTH);
mainPanel.add(topCenter,BorderLayout.NORTH);
mainPanel.add(topRight,BorderLayout.NORTH);
mainPanel.add(centerLeft,BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(centerCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(centerRight,BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(bottomLeft,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
mainPanel.add(bottomCenter,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
mainPanel.add(bottomRight,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

this.setTitle("Dice Game");
this.setBounds(200, 200, 700, 700);
this.add(mainPanel);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.pack();

}

private class RollListener1 implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
myLeftDie.roll();
}
}
private class RollListener2 implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
myRightDie.roll();
}  
}
}
class Dice extends JPanel {

private static final int SPOT_DIAMETER = 4;

private int myFaceValue;
public Dice() {
setBackground(Color.white);
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(15,15));
roll();
}

int roll() {
int val = (int)(6*Math.random() + 1);
setValue(val);
return val;
}

public int getValue() {
return myFaceValue;
}

public void setValue(int spots) {
myFaceValue = spots;
repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);

int w = getWidth();
int h = getHeight();

g.drawRect(0, 0, w-1, h-1);

switch (myFaceValue) {
case 1: drawSpot(g, w/2, h/2);
    break;
case 3: drawSpot(g, w/2, h/2);

case 2: drawSpot(g, w/4, h/4);
    drawSpot(g, 3*w/4, 3*h/4);
    break;
case 5: drawSpot(g, w/2, h/2);

case 4: drawSpot(g, w/4, h/4);
    drawSpot(g, 3*w/4, 3*h/4);
    drawSpot(g, 3*w/4, h/4);
    drawSpot(g, w/4, 3*h/4);
    break;
case 6: drawSpot(g, w/4, h/4);
    drawSpot(g, 3*w/4, 3*h/4);
    drawSpot(g, 3*w/4, h/4);
    drawSpot(g, w/4, 3*h/4);
    drawSpot(g, w/4, h/2);
    drawSpot(g, 3*w/4, h/2);
    break;
}
}

private void drawSpot(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
g.fillOval(x-SPOT_DIAMETER/2, y-SPOT_DIAMETER/2, SPOT_DIAMETER, SPOT_DIAMETER);
}
}
```

Comment: Why have you deleted your last question on this topic?

Comment: Because I wanted to add more to the question @camickr

Comment: @camickr could you please help me with the code , I absolutely can't think of a way to do it

Comment: *"I wanted to add more to the question"* You can [edit] your own question (or answer) at any time. Don't delete them, as it loses potentially valuable comments & answers! Minus one.

Comment: **BTW:** 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: *I absolutely can't think of a way to do it* - the suggestion I made was to use a `GridLayout` for the main panel. That was an easy change for you to make. I still don't really understand the rest of the question so I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed up your GUI.

[image: Dice Game]

I started your GUI with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created the `JFrame` in your class constructor.  I created an outer `JPanel`, eight inner `JPanels`, and a center `JPanel`.  The `JFrame` methods must be executed in a specific order.  This is the order I use for my Swing GUIs.

The outer `JPanel` uses a `GridLayout` to organize the inner `JPanels`.  The eight inner `JPanels` are similar, so I used a method to create them.

The center `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout` to organize the `JButtons` and die images.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DiceGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RollDicePanel();
            }
        });
    }
}

class RollDicePanel extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private Dice myLeftDie;
    private Dice myRightDie;

    public RollDicePanel() {
        this.setTitle("Dice Game");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(createOuterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createOuterPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        panel.add(createInnerPanel("+20", new Color(152, 254, 152), 
                Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(createInnerPanel("Try Again...", new Color(252, 252, 201), 
                Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(createInnerPanel("-50", new Color(254, 152, 152), 
                Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(createInnerPanel("Finish!",new Color(0, 203, 101), 
                Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(createCenterPanel());
        panel.add(createInnerPanel("Lost All",new Color(252, 48, 99), 
                Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(createInnerPanel("-10", new Color(254, 203, 203), 
                Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(createInnerPanel("+10", new Color(203, 254, 203), 
                Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(createInnerPanel("+30", new Color(49, 253, 0), 
                Color.BLACK));
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createInnerPanel(String text, Color backgroundColor, 
            Color foregroundColor) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        label.setForeground(foregroundColor);
        panel.add(label);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createCenterPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JButton rollButton1 = new JButton("Player 1");
        rollButton1.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 10));
        rollButton1.addActionListener(new RollListener1());
        panel.add(rollButton1, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        JButton rollButton2 = new JButton("Player 2");
        rollButton2.setFont(new Font("Sansserif", Font.BOLD, 10));
        rollButton2.addActionListener(new RollListener2());
        panel.add(rollButton2, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        myLeftDie = new Dice();
        panel.add(myLeftDie, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        myRightDie = new Dice();
        panel.add(myRightDie, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }

    private class RollListener1 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            myLeftDie.roll();
        }
    }

    private class RollListener2 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            myRightDie.roll();
        }
    }
}

class Dice extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int SPOT_DIAMETER = 4;

    private int myFaceValue;

    public Dice() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(15, 15));
        roll();
    }

    int roll() {
        int val = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
        setValue(val);
        return val;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return myFaceValue;
    }

    public void setValue(int spots) {
        myFaceValue = spots;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        g.drawRect(0, 0, w - 1, h - 1);

        switch (myFaceValue) {
        case 1:
            drawSpot(g, w / 2, h / 2);
            break;
        case 3:
            drawSpot(g, w / 2, h / 2);

        case 2:
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            break;
        case 5:
            drawSpot(g, w / 2, h / 2);

        case 4:
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            break;
        case 6:
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 2);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, h / 2);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void drawSpot(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.fillOval(x - SPOT_DIAMETER / 2, y - SPOT_DIAMETER / 2, 
                SPOT_DIAMETER, SPOT_DIAMETER);
    }
}
```

### Update 1

I went ahead and finished the game.

[image: Dice Game 2]

I created a logical model to hold the board squares and the player positions and score for player 1 and player 2.

I modified the view to use the logical model.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DiceGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RollDicePanel();
            }
        });
    }
}

class RollDicePanel extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private final DiceGameModel model;
    
    private Dice myLeftDie;
    private Dice myRightDie;
    
    private InnerSquarePanel[] innerPanels;
    
    private JTextField scoreField1;
    private JTextField scoreField2;

    public RollDicePanel() {
        this.model = new DiceGameModel();
        
        this.setTitle("Dice Game");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(createOuterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createOuterPanel() {
        int length = model.getBoardSquares().size();
        this.innerPanels = new InnerSquarePanel[length];
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            innerPanels[index] = new InnerSquarePanel(
                    model.getBoardSquares().get(index)); 
        }
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        panel.add(innerPanels[1].getPanel());
        panel.add(innerPanels[2].getPanel());
        panel.add(innerPanels[3].getPanel());
        panel.add(innerPanels[0].getPanel());
        panel.add(createCenterPanel());
        panel.add(innerPanels[4].getPanel());
        panel.add(innerPanels[7].getPanel());
        panel.add(innerPanels[6].getPanel());
        panel.add(innerPanels[5].getPanel());
        
        innerPanels[0].getPlayer1Label().setText("Player 1");
        innerPanels[0].getPlayer2Label().setText("Player 2");
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createCenterPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JButton rollButton1 = new JButton("Player 1");
        rollButton1.setFont(font);
        rollButton1.addActionListener(new RollListener1());
        panel.add(rollButton1, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        JButton rollButton2 = new JButton("Player 2");
        rollButton2.setFont(font);
        rollButton2.addActionListener(new RollListener2());
        panel.add(rollButton2, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        myLeftDie = new Dice();
        panel.add(myLeftDie, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        myRightDie = new Dice();
        panel.add(myRightDie, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Score");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        label = new JLabel("Score");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        scoreField1 = new JTextField(4);
        scoreField1.setEditable(false);
        scoreField1.setFont(font);
        scoreField1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        panel.add(scoreField1, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        scoreField2 = new JTextField(4);
        scoreField2.setEditable(false);
        scoreField2.setFont(font);
        scoreField2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        panel.add(scoreField2, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }

    private class RollListener1 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int position = model.getPlayer1position();
            int roll = myLeftDie.roll();
            
            model.incrementPlayer1position(roll);
            BoardSquare boardSquare = model.getBoardSquares().get(
                    model.getPlayer1position());
            int score = boardSquare.execute(model.getPlayer1score());
            model.setPlayer1score(score);
            
            innerPanels[position].getPlayer1Label().setText(" ");
            innerPanels[model.getPlayer1position()].getPlayer1Label().
                    setText("Player 1");
            scoreField1.setText(Integer.toString(score));
        }
    }

    private class RollListener2 implements ActionListener {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int position = model.getPlayer2position();
            int roll = myRightDie.roll();
            
            model.incrementPlayer2position(roll);
            BoardSquare boardSquare = model.getBoardSquares().get(
                    model.getPlayer2position());
            int score = boardSquare.execute(model.getPlayer2score());
            model.setPlayer2score(score);
            
            innerPanels[position].getPlayer2Label().setText(" ");
            innerPanels[model.getPlayer2position()].getPlayer2Label().
                    setText("Player 2");
            scoreField2.setText(Integer.toString(score));
        }
    }
    
}

class Dice extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int SPOT_DIAMETER = 4;

    private int myFaceValue;

    public Dice() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(15, 15));
        roll();
    }

    int roll() {
        int val = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1);
        setValue(val);
        return val;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return myFaceValue;
    }

    public void setValue(int spots) {
        myFaceValue = spots;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        g.drawRect(0, 0, w - 1, h - 1);

        switch (myFaceValue) {
        case 1:
            drawSpot(g, w / 2, h / 2);
            break;
        case 3:
            drawSpot(g, w / 2, h / 2);

        case 2:
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            break;
        case 5:
            drawSpot(g, w / 2, h / 2);

        case 4:
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            break;
        case 6:
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
            drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 2);
            drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, h / 2);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void drawSpot(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.fillOval(x - SPOT_DIAMETER / 2, y - SPOT_DIAMETER / 2, 
                SPOT_DIAMETER, SPOT_DIAMETER);
    }
    
}

class InnerSquarePanel {
    
    private JLabel player1Label;
    private JLabel player2Label;
    
    private final JPanel panel;
    
    public InnerSquarePanel(BoardSquare boardSquare) {
        this.panel =  createInnerPanel(boardSquare);
    }
    
    private JPanel createInnerPanel(BoardSquare boardSquare) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(boardSquare.getBackgroundColor());
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10 ,10);
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(boardSquare.getText());
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
        label.setForeground(boardSquare.getForegroundColor());
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        player1Label = new JLabel(" ");
        player1Label.setForeground(boardSquare.getForegroundColor());
        player1Label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEADING);
        player1Label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        panel.add(player1Label, gbc);
        
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.gridx++;
        player2Label = new JLabel(" ");
        player2Label.setForeground(boardSquare.getForegroundColor());
        player2Label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.TRAILING);
        player2Label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        panel.add(player2Label, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }

    public JLabel getPlayer1Label() {
        return player1Label;
    }

    public JLabel getPlayer2Label() {
        return player2Label;
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }
    
}

class DiceGameModel {
    
    private int player1position;
    private int player2position;
    private int player1score;
    private int player2score;
    
    private final List<BoardSquare> boardSquares;
    
    public DiceGameModel() {
        this.player1position = 0;
        this.player2position = 0;
        this.player1score = 0;
        this.player2score = 0;
        
        this.boardSquares = new ArrayList<>();
        boardSquares.add(new FinishSquare());
        boardSquares.add(new Square1());
        boardSquares.add(new Square2());
        boardSquares.add(new Square3());
        boardSquares.add(new Square4());
        boardSquares.add(new Square5());
        boardSquares.add(new Square6());
        boardSquares.add(new Square7());
    }

    public int getPlayer1position() {
        return player1position;
    }

    public void incrementPlayer1position(int increment) {
        this.player1position = (player1position + increment) % 
                boardSquares.size();
    }

    public int getPlayer2position() {
        return player2position;
    }

    public void incrementPlayer2position(int increment) {
        this.player2position = (player2position + increment) % 
                boardSquares.size();
    }

    public int getPlayer1score() {
        return player1score;
    }

    public void setPlayer1score(int player1score) {
        this.player1score = player1score;
    }

    public int getPlayer2score() {
        return player2score;
    }

    public void setPlayer2score(int player2score) {
        this.player2score = player2score;
    }

    public List<BoardSquare> getBoardSquares() {
        return boardSquares;
    }
    
}

class FinishSquare extends BoardSquare {
    
    public FinishSquare() {
        super("Finish!", 0, new Color(0, 203, 101), Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public int execute(int score) {
        return score;
    }
    
}

class Square1 extends BoardSquare {
    
    public Square1() {
        super("+20", 1, new Color(152, 254, 152), Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public int execute(int score) {
        return score + 20;
    }
    
}

class Square2 extends BoardSquare {
    
    public Square2() {
        super("Try Again", 2, new Color(252, 252, 201), Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public int execute(int score) {
        return score;
    }
    
}

class Square3 extends BoardSquare {
    
    public Square3() {
        super("-50", 3, new Color(254, 152, 152), Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public int execute(int score) {
        return score - 50;
    }
    
}

class Square4 extends BoardSquare {
    
    public Square4() {
        super("Lost All", 4, new Color(252, 48, 99), Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public int execute(int score) {
        return 0;
    }
    
}

class Square5 extends BoardSquare {
    
    public Square5() {
        super("+30", 5, new Color(49, 253, 0), Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public int execute(int score) {
        return score + 30;
    }
    
}

class Square6 extends BoardSquare {
    
    public Square6() {
        super("+10", 6, new Color(203, 254, 203), Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public int execute(int score) {
        return score + 10;
    }
    
}

class Square7 extends BoardSquare {
    
    public Square7() {
        super("-10", 7, new Color(254, 203, 203), Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public int execute(int score) {
        return score - 10;
    }
    
}

abstract class BoardSquare {
    
    private final int position;
    
    private final Color backgroundColor;
    private final Color foregroundColor;
    
    private final String text;
    
    public BoardSquare(String text, int position,  
            Color backgroundColor,  Color foregroundColor) {
        this.text = text;
        this.position = position;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        this.foregroundColor = foregroundColor;
    }
    
    public abstract int execute(int score);

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Color getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public Color getForegroundColor() {
        return foregroundColor;
    }

}
```